# "The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception."- how to fix this?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I'm working with WPF. When I'm trying to declare `SQLiteConnection` in the code, the problem arises-

```
The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

InnerException: Make sure that the file is a valid .NET Framework assembly.
```

can anyone tell me, how to fix it?

Comment: Please show the code of the mentioned constructor. It looks like you are trying to load a file as an assembly that isn't a .NET assembly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the below content in `app.config`,

```
<configuration> <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" /> </configuration>
```

I found this via a community addition by user [FCAA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/fcaa/) below the article ["
Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.IO.FileLoadException"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHFILELOAD%29&rd=true) on MSDN.

Comment: https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/67899834.jpg good job figuring it out though and informing others about it.

Comment: Could've also been something like the default namespce

Answer (score 51):

If you click on **View Detail...** from the exception window you can look at the **InnerException**. Expand that node and you will see exactly what went wrong.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer to everyone's question.   It ought to be marked as the answer.  It's surprising how many people don't bother to look at (or don't know about) the InnerException

Comment: I initially read this as condescension because of Joe's comment but you're correct. This is one of those rare cases where a useless error message has great content hiding inside.

Comment: Where is the exception window?

Comment: @Demodave - assuming you are using Visual Studio, the exception windows pops up when the debugger catches the error.

Answer (score 25):

In my specific case, I was getting this because I had a few of my referencing assemblies mismatched between x64 and x86.  Apparently I was binding to something that needed to be loaded by the runtime.

I mention this here as a reminder to check your build configurations if you've looked everywhere else!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and, after wasting about 2 hours with it, found that it is my SQL Server service that's not running.  Not sure if this can ever help someone, but it did solve my problem to just start the service.

Answer (score 5):

The mentioned exeption is quite generic and you can receive it, for instance, when code fails in the constructor. I had a case of an IO exception that showed up with a similar text. Stepping into the code may provide hints to fix this that may not be obvious otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I got it in when I specified the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` of a `DependencyProperty` with a default value

the defaultValue was

```
new AdressRecord { Name = "<new>", Adress = "?" }
```

i replaced with

```
default(AddressRecord)
```

and vs2015 ate it

```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty AdressRecordsProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("AdressRecords", 
           typeof(ObservableCollection<AdressRecord>), 
           typeof(PageViewModel), 
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
               default(AdressRecord),//This noes not work: new AdressRecord { Name = "<new>", Adress = "?" },
               OnAdressRecordsChanged));
```

Comment: This gave me the clue I needed to solve my own deviously subtle issue. In my case, the `DependencyProperty`'s underlying type was `double`, but I had assigned it a default value of `0` (an `int`). Changing the default value to `0.0` allowed the program to run correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and it was caused because my startup application was built as any CPU but I was referencing a project that was built as x64. Setting the startup to build x64 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In VS2015 I was able to see the specific code causing this problem once I turned on 'Enable Just My Code' in the Debugging Options under Tools -> Options.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in another part of code which has to do with my application resources.

This was fixed after explicitly setting the `ResourcePath` folder in my `App.config` file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. i could make it work by renaming the name of App1.config to App.config. I tried all other methods but the solution for me was to change the default name (for me it was App1.config) of the config file to App.config. I shared this because someone may get help by this small modification.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was about the interface. I fixed it by deleting the Betternet folder that is located at `C:\ProgramData`.

> Hidden Items/Folders must be shown in order to be able to view the folder.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio it will sometimes not show anything in the exception details or even have them, running the diagnostic tool however can easily pinpoint what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding "Integreted Security = True" in Connection String.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened in a code-first WPF project. The cause was model changes after restoring a backup, and the error was not being handled appropriately. "The model backing the 'MyDataContext' context has changed since the database was created." Update-Database sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the target .Net framework from 4.5.2 to 4.

Comment: Most likely the client system did not have .net 4.5.2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was regular System.IndexOutOfRangeException error in my own code,
but received this weird error because my code was called inside:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // my code with error
}
```

same issue, if call it inside:

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // my code with error
}
```

Fixed, if I call my code inside:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // my code with error
}
```

Then i get correct error message for IndexOutOfRangeException in my code.