# SQLite Exception With WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

*Framework* : .NetFrameWork 4.0
*Application* : Visual Studio 2012
*Windows* : 7 X64
Applcation Target : X86
*Details* : I've used System.Data.SQLite Assembly for Applications in WinForms and it was working but When I used it with WPF It throws exception.

Here`s My Code :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ModernLab.db;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Version=3;");
            SQLiteCommand cm = new SQLiteCommand();
            SQLiteCommand cm2 = new SQLiteCommand();
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter;
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select VisitID as 'رقم الزيارة',Name as 'اسم المريض',VisitDate as 'تاريخ الزيارة',DeilveryDate as 'تاريخ الاستلام' from Visits", cn);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dgvRecieve.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
        }
```

> Exeption thrown ('The invocation of the constructor on type 'ModernSoft_Lab_System.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9')

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all the code after `InitializeComponent` and then running it? I suspect it is something in your XAML that is screwed up.

Comment: Please post the InnerException. There you can see the real problem. And maybe have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the

Comment: the problem appeared only when using any of Classes in System.Data.SQLite as SQLiteConnection or SQLiteCommand or SQLiteDataAdapter

Comment: and how I can get inner exception of this code?? I have tried try and catch for this code but the exception is thrown from somecode behind

Answer (score 0):

SQLite connections do not support the MultipleActiveResultSets parameter.