# Exception thrown while defining a query and connecting to Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The exception that was thrown was

> "“The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWPF.MainWindow' that
>   matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.”"
>   Which I have googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the) and several like it. All of which say to add `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />` to you configuration file.

I have a method called GetCustomers:

```
void GetCustomers()
{
    var context = new ContactTestEntities();
    var query = from c in context.ContactTs
        select c;
    Listbox.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

It will throws the exception when on `var query = from c in context.Contacts select c;`

my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="True" />
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContactTestEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/ContactTest.csdl|res://*/ContactTest.ssdl|res://*/ContactTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQL;
         initial catalog=ContactTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

please tell me if you see something incorrect here. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after an hour of digging I figured out that there wasn't anything wrong with the code. The problem was that I didn't have the config file in the startup file. So that is the answer put your connection string into the startup file.