# Source Not Available in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Anyone please help me to fix my problem. The error is:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWs.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.

Also showing:

> Source information is missing from debug information for this module.

I viewed in disassembly window it shows like:

```
01112DE1 mov dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax




<Window x:Class="TestWs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWs"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="467" Width="799" Background="#FF617EB0">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateItemDirect">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" ></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding userid}" Grid.Column="0" Width="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" Width="150"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding PictureString}" Grid.Column="2" Name="ImageName" Height="15" Width="15" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" Width="700" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Label Name="lbAddress" Height="30" Width="60" Content="Address:" Margin="10,0,0,0"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="txtAddr" Width="350" Height="20" Text="ws://localhost:52804/WSHandler.ashx"></TextBox>
                <Button Name="btConnect" Height="20" Width="80" Content="Connect" Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="btConnect_Click"></Button>
                <Button Name="btDisconnect" Height="20" Width="80" Content="Disconnect" Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="btDisconnect_Click"></Button>
               <!--  <Button Name="btLogin" Width="80" Height="20" Content="Logout" Margin="10,10,0,0" Click="btLogin_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>  -->
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top"  DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <Label Name="lbUser" Height="auto" Width="auto"  Margin="5" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Cambria"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnChat"  Width="100" Height="30" Content="Chat" Click="btnChat_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="btnFileTransfer" Width="100" Height="30" Content="File Transfer" Click="btnFileTransfer_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="button3" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Notification" Click="button3_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="button5" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Group Create" Click="button5_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="button6" Width="100" Height="30" Content="GPS Msg" Click="button6_Click"/>
                 <Button x:Name="button4" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Remove User" Click="button4_Click"/> 
                <!--    <Button x:Name="button7" Width="100" Height="30" Content="button" Click="button7_Click"/>  -->
             <!--   <Button x:Name="button8" Width="100" Height="30" Content="UserList" Click="button8_Click"/> -->

            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="270" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Group" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  />
                    <!-- <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="100" Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" /> -->
                    <!--   <DataGrid x:Name="grdGroup" Width="250" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="grdGroup_SelectionChanged_1" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedValuePath ="GroupId" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group ID"  Binding="{Binding GroupId}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Name" Binding="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParentId" Binding="{Binding ParentId}"/> 
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding subgrp}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid> -->

                    <ListBox Name="lbGroupList" Width="auto" Height="130" Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Right"   SelectionChanged="lbGroupList_SelectionChanged" SelectedValuePath ="GroupId" >

                        <ListBox.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <ScrollViewer>
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="White">
                                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="CadetBlue" >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>

                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Group Id"></Label>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Group Name"></Label>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Group"></Label>

                                        </Grid>
                                        <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ListBox.Template>

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Grid>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupId}"  Grid.Column="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>

                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding subgrp}" Grid.Column="2"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                    <Label x:Name="lblUser" Content="User" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top"   />

                    <ListBox x:Name="LstUserList" Height="130" Margin="5,0,5,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"   ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplateItemDirect}"  SelectionChanged="LstUserList_SelectionChanged_1" ItemsSource="{Binding UserDisplay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto"  >
                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="White">
                                    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="CadetBlue" >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" ></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="User Id"></Label>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="User Name"></Label>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Status"></Label>

                                    </Grid>
                                    <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>
                    </ListBox>

                    <!--   <TextBox Name="txtRecivemessage" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsReadOnly="True"  /> -->
                    <!-- <ListBox x:Name="lstUser"  Margin="5"/> -->
                    <!--
                    <DataGrid x:Name="grdUsers"   Height="121" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="grdUsers_SelectionChanged_1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="User ID"  Binding="{Binding UserId}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Name" Binding="{Binding UserName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding StatusName}"/>
                             <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="delete">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Command="Delete" Content="Remove" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid> -->
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>

            <StackPanel x:Name="stkUsrContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <!-- <local:UctrlLogIn Width="400" Height="215" Loaded="UctrlLogIn_Loaded" />   -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>


    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: try adding this `<configuration> <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" /> </configuration>` in  `app.config`

Comment: Can you include the source of `MainWindow`?

Comment: I add <configuration> <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" /> </configuration> in my app.config still showing same error

Comment: I solve that problem.  I check all CLR exceptions so i found where that exception occurred.  I convert 0 as DateTime format and assigned it to another DateTime variable so it just cause an exception so that only i couldn't run my solution.   Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the)

They added this to app.config

```
<configuration> <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" /> </configuration>
```