# CLR20r3 error WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Im deploying my WPF app on a Windows Server 2012 R2
Here is my error message :

> Problem signature :   Event Name signature : CLR20r3
>
> Problem signature 01:   MyApp.exe
>
> Problem signature 02:   1.0.0.0
>
> Problem signature 03:   5a3a6ef1
>
> Problem signature 04:   mscorlib
>
> Problem signature 05:   4.7.2117.0
>
> Problem signature 06:   59cf500c
>
> Problem signature 07:   165d
>
> Problem signature 08:   fc
>
> Problem signature 09:   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
>
> Systeme Version:    6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
>
> Identificateur de paramètres régionaux: 1036
>
> Information supplémentaire n° 1:    5861
>
> Information supplémentaire n° 2:    5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
>
> Information supplémentaire n° 3:    5f25
>
> Information supplémentaire n° 4:    5f2531ae070278f893fa99352dadd49e

Comment: Problem signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse you have problem in your xaml files

Comment: Why it works locally ?

Comment: Maybe on the server you do not have some DLL-s: you can check if you copy all libraries- references to deploy folder or you are taking it from the GAC. In server version of OS, some sort of assemblies could be not added to GAC ( Global Assemblies cache).

Comment: All my used dlls are inclued in the deploy (.application)

Comment: Did you try to turn of the antivirus protection:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995318/system-windows-markup-xamlparseexception-it-seems-to-be-heisenbug

Comment: here is another potential cause. Check the xaml references. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/729ee339-a9ba-47a8-b161-089743de9fce/installation-and-run-issues-with-deployed-wpf-app?forum=wpf

Comment: I have added a Listener on DispatcherUnhandledException in my app.xaml and I have this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the