# Unable to load Outlook add-in user control on customer deployment when Outlook run without 'Run As administrator'

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an *Outlook COM Add-in*, which is deployed on *Windows 10* (German locale) on customer setup. If I run Outlook application with 'Run as administrator' then everything works fine.

But if I run Outlook without 'Run as administrator' then I get following exception.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Aktiveringen af
>   konstruktøren på typen 'OfficePlugin.UserControlContact', som svarer
>   til de angivne bindingsbegrænsninger, udløste en undtagelse. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Ressourcen
>   view/usercontrols/usercontrolcontact.xaml blev ikke fundet.

I carried following tests on customer setup but no success.

1. Install Outlook add-in by running installer **as administrator**
2. Install Outlook add-in in **custom folder** , outside **C:\Program files (x86)** folder.
3. Reinstalled *Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime* manually

I am unable to understand why Outlook add-in is unable to access the resource file from 'de-DE' folder(when run without 'Run as administrator'). Please help me on how should I troubleshoot this issue.

Customer does **not** want to run Outlook *as administrator*.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Aktiveringen af
>   konstruktøren på typen 'OfficePlugin.UserControlContact', som svarer
>   til de angivne bindingsbegrænsninger, udløste en undtagelse. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Ressourcen
>   view/usercontrols/usercontrolcontact.xaml blev ikke fundet.
>
> ved MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access)
>
> ved System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access)
>
> ved System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
>
> ved System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="OfficePlugin.UserControlContact"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:OfficePlugin="clr-namespace:OfficePlugin"
         x:Name="UserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseEnter="control_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="control_MouseLeave"  d:DesignHeight="152" d:DesignWidth="277" Height="Auto" Width="257" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <OfficePlugin:StatusIconConverter x:Key="statusIconConverter"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type OfficePlugin:UserControlContact}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="GridBackground" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="GridHeight" Value="548" />
                <Setter Property="StatusVisibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>

<!--<Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,0"  BorderThickness ="0" Width="Auto" Height ="Auto">-->

    <Grid x:Name="GridContact" Background="Transparent" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="548" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="287" MouseEnter="control_MouseEnter" DataContext="Contact">


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="37*" />
            <!--<RowDefinition Height="23*" />-->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="ContactBorder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Width="255" Height ="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding StatusVisibility}" DataContext="UserControlContact">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="3" />
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <OfficePlugin:UserControlContactHeader x:Name ="ContactHeader" ContactRef="{Binding DirectoryContact}"  Grid.Row="1" Width="252" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto"/>

    <Grid x:Name="StatusPop"  Grid.Row="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding StatusVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="UserControlContact" MouseEnter="control_MouseEnter">
        <OfficePlugin:UserControlPresencePop  x:Name="PresencePop" Height="Auto" Margin="3,0,6,0" DataContext="Contact" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Please post relevant parts of your XAML.

Comment: Posted with UserControlContact XAML

Comment: Change your project to run Outlook.exe in the debugger then you can catch the exception in action.  Failing that, after translating your exception with Google, [this possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the) may be useful

Comment: You should translate those errors into English.