# What can cause an error in InitializeComponent method?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have an app, which can execute another app by the path to *.exe file. Both work well on my computer, but on the other one I get an error: 
"Setting property System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content has thrown an exception at string 33, position 6."

I've tried to track it, so I exactly know, that it happens in InitializeComponent method of the second app. Then I catched the error from this method and the message was: "
An exception was thrown when calling a constructor of the type 'UPR.FeedBack.App.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints (string 9, position 23)" But I can't even imagine, why does it happen.

Also I thought, that the problem is in missing some *.dll files on the second machine, but I have set all the references of the project to be copied locally.

And I've tried to execute it without assigning Datacontext and configuring window, it didn't solve this.

Executing the process:

```
        process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Verb = "Open",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                Arguments = string.Join(" ", userName),
                WorkingDirectory = processPath
            }
        };

        process.Start();
```

MAINWINDOW.xaml.cs(second app):

```
namespace UPR.FeedBack.App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
            ConfigureWindow();
        }
     }
}
```

MAINWINDOW.xaml(second app):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" x:Class="UPR.FeedBack.App.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                  xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InfrastructureLight.Common.Helpers;assembly=InfrastructureLight.Common"
                  mc:Ignorable="d"
                  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UPR.FeedBack.App"
                  Title="Title"                      
                  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MainWindow}">
```

So as I see, the error is in ' xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:UPR.FeedBack.App" '. But the namespace is right. And again: the apps work on my computer without any errors, but on others I get such problems.

Comment: Could you provide deeper  inner exception ? (in your case it is inner inside inner exception)

Comment: I was difficult to provide it, because of second machine is not mine, and there is no debugger there, but I did it) found the problem, thank you) @Bondarenko

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide detailed sub inner exception ?

Also could look this post it might be useful in your case.

["The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception."- how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987091/the-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-testwpf-mainwindow-that-matches-the)